# explain these xml files what i have written of magento

Tags: magento

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/module_config.xml
In this website full information is not available
can u explain what i have written........................................................................

```
<blocks>
        <helloworld>
            <rewrite>
                    <helloworld>M4U_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld</helloworld>
             </rewrite>
        </helloworld>
 </blocks> 
    </global>



   <frontend>
            <routers>
                    <helloworld>
                            <use>standard</use>
                            <args>
                                  <module>M4U_HelloWorld</module>
                                  <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                            </args>
                    </helloworld>
            </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <helloworld>
                  <file>helloworld.xml</file>
            </helloworld>
        </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<global>    
     <blocks>
            <helloworld>
                <rewrite>
                        <helloworld>M4U_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld</helloworld>
                 </rewrite>
            </helloworld>
     </blocks> 
</global>
```

This says that you are overwriting the block Helloworld block class of Helloworld module. It means whenever a call is made for this block class then it will first do to this class M4U_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld and then the HelloWorld_Block_Hellword class.

```
<frontend>
            <routers>
                    <helloworld>
                            <use>standard</use>
                            <args>
                                  <module>M4U_HelloWorld</module>
                                  <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                            </args>
                    </helloworld>
            </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <helloworld>
                  <file>helloworld.xml</file>
            </helloworld>
        </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
```

Routers: Using this tag you are giving the frontname for module to get accessed through url. You have given frontName as "helloworld". 
When you type www.example.com/helloworld in browser then magento will pass the control to class M4U_Helloworld_IndexController of M4U_HelloWorld module.

layout: This tab tells magento system that all your handler and layout updates are written under helloworld.xml file. Here you can assign template files to your block class and can tell which template should be called when particular action is accessed by customer.

This is a informal explanation. For complete knowledge you can refer to [alanstorm.com/](http://alanstorm.com/)

Comment: it tells magento system that you are overriding class.

Comment: Block is the class that is used by the phtml. You can call the method of block class using $this.

Comment: what is use and args?

Comment: this is arguments. which is passing module name and front name.

Comment: i can't chat because i have only 8 reputation so  can u explain what is use if i delete the <use> tag then what happens?

Comment: that means – Magento will use the standard router for processing requests and URLs. So for frontend you have to use this until and unless you are changing way to handle request. [link](http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_standard_router) and this [link2](http://www.atwix.com/magento/create-custom-router/)

Answer (score 0):

In the above xml file

```
<blocks>
        <helloworld>
            <rewrite>
                    <helloworld>M4U_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld</helloworld>
             </rewrite>
        </helloworld>
 </blocks>
```

this code is used to override the block. See the detail info [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

```
<routers>
                    <helloworld>
                            <use>standard</use>
                            <args>
                                  <module>M4U_HelloWorld</module>
                                  <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                            </args>
                    </helloworld>
            </routers>
```

This block of code relates to below

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>PackageName_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

The `<frontend>` tag will tell Magento about the controller dispatched. Inside the `<frontend>` tag, we have defined `<routers>` that tells Magento how to access our controllers via the routing mechanism.

In the `<mymodule>` tag, we have defined module name in `<module>` tag and frontend name in `<frontName>`. By using a frontend name, we can access our module in frontend like

> yoursitename.com/index.php/mymodule/index.

For layout tabs [here](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/16336482158/adding-additional-layout-xml-updates-via-modules) is the great explaination by alan strom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: <rewrite> tag lets the magento execution to know that the particular block is overridden by the below class.which will help to get the execution to the class that you have mentioned after <rewrite> block.